# AWS CLI --output text on a single line of first and second level json

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to get a list of certificates (let's say 100) from AWS Certificates Manager with their Domain Name, Expiry Data, Validation Status and Validation Method with the aws cli command `aws acm describe-certificate`.

I tried nesting filtering and `--ouput text` but the output is on two lines. I guess the reason is that ValidationStatus and ValidationMethod are second level in the json ouput after Certificate/DomainValidationOptions.

How would it be possible to get the text ouput in a single line?

Like

```
foo.bar.com    2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00 FAILED  DNS
```

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html

This is the `--output text`

```bash
$ aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:region:aws-account_id:certificate/xxxx  --query Certificate.[DomainName,NotAfter,DomainValidationOptions[].[ValidationStatus,ValidationMethod]] --output text
foo.bar.com    2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00
FAILED  DNS
```

This is the `--output json` (default output)

```
 aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:region:aws-account_id:certificate/xxxx  --query Certificate.[DomainName,NotAfter,DomainValidationOptions[].[ValidationStatus,ValidationMethod]]
[
    "foo.bar.com",
    2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00,
    [
        [
            "FAILED",
            "DNS"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: It might be because it is attempting to list all elements of the List (even though there is only one entry). Perhaps you could try using `DomainValidationOptions[0]` to only retrieve the _first_ entry in the list?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein _even though there is only one entry_ > that's not what the OP is stating: _I am trying to get a list of certificates (let's say 100)_

Comment: I dropped a first path of solution, but you might want to complexify your example for more than one domain, because a solution to the issue at end could end up having only one line with the 100 domains, which is maybe also not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A way to achieve this is to flatten the array you are receiving from the AWS command, with the help of the JMESPath [flatten operator — `[]`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) — in your query.

Having a query like this:

```
Certificate.[
  DomainName,
  NotAfter,
  DomainValidationOptions[].[ValidationStatus, ValidationMethod]
][][]
```

Would give you, with one domain the JSON output

```json
[
  "www.example.com",
  "2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00",
  "FAILED",
  "DNS"
]
```

And end up on one line.

---

Now mind that, if you have more than one item in the `DomainValidationOptions` array, they will, then, all output on the same line, because you'll have one array with everything.

Example for two domains:

```json
[
  "www.example.com",
  "2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00",
  "FAILED",
  "DNS",
  "FAILED",
  "DNS"
]
```

See the DNS and `ValidationStatus` and `ValidationMethod` repeating for the two domains there?

What you might want to do, is to query the `DomainName` from the DomainValidationOptions, at least:

```json
Certificate.[
  NotAfter,
  DomainValidationOptions[].[DomainName, ValidationStatus, ValidationMethod]
][][]
```

Which would still be on one line, but will get you the domain related to the validation:

```json
[
  "2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00",
  "www.example.com",
  "FAILED",
  "DNS",
  "www.example.net",
  "FAILED",
  "DNS"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some progress was made using John's suggestion. 
By using "InUseBy[0]" and not only "InUseBy", I managed to output the "InUseBy" on the first line; otherwise it would be on the second line.

Also using "DomainValidationOptions[0].ValidationStatus" instead of "DomainValidationOptions.ValidationStatus" outputs this on the 2nd line instead of 3rd.

Still, I would like

```
"RenewalSummary.[RenewalStatus,DomainValidationOptions[0].ValidationStatus]"
```

**to be output on the first line too.** I noticed RenewalSummary is an object ,{}, not an array, [].

```
  "RenewalSummary": {
            "RenewalStatus": "PENDING_VALIDATION",
            "DomainValidationOptions": [
                {
                    "DomainName": "foo.bar.com",
                    "ValidationDomain": "foo.bar.com",
                    "ValidationStatus": "PENDING_VALIDATION",
                    "ResourceRecord": {
                        "Name": "_9d77eed0XXX66.foo.bar.com.",
                        "Type": "CNAME",
                        "Value": "_a5XXXX3.tgztlnjmjp.acm-validations.aws."
                    },
                    "ValidationMethod": "DNS"
                }
            ],
            "UpdatedAt": "2022-06-24T11:16:34.617000+00:00"
        },
```

```
aws acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn arn:aws:acm:region:aws-account_id:certificate/xxxx --query Certificate.[DomainName,Issuer,Status,FailureReason,NotAfter,InUseBy[0],RenewalSummary.[RenewalStatus,DomainValidationOptions[0].ValidationStatus]] --output text
```

This is how the output looks now:

```
foo.bar.com  Amazon  ISSUED  None    2022-06-18T23:59:59+00:00       arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:aws_account_id:loadbalancer/app/alb_foo_bar/XXX
PENDING_VALIDATION      PENDING_VALIDATION
```